# Grouping into interval of 2 minutes within a time range

Tags: mysql

i have some issue with grouping the data in interval of 2 minutes.
here is my table data

| ticker | open | high | low | close | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APPL | 1940 | 1950 | 1935 | 1948 | 2023-03-20 11:00:00 |
| APPL | 1950 | 1960 | 1945 | 1958 | 2023-03-20 11:01:00 |
| APPL | 1960 | 1970 | 1955 | 1968 | 2023-03-20 11:02:00 |
| APPL | 1970 | 1980 | 1965 | 1978 | 2023-03-20 11:03:00 |
| APPL | 1980 | 1990 | 1985 | 1998 | 2023-03-20 11:04:00 |
| APPL | 1990 | 2000 | 1975 | 1988 | 2023-03-20 11:05:00 |

My query:

```
select
  open,
  MAX(high) as high,
  MIN(low) as low,
  close,
  time,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)/120 ) * 120) AS quaterhour
from tableName
where ticker = 'APPL'
group by quaterhour
order by quaterhour ASC
```

Expected output:

| ticker | open | high | low | close | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APPL | 1940 | 1960 | 1935 | 1958 | 2023-03-20 11:00:00 |
| APPL | 1960 | 1980 | 1955 | 1978 | 2023-03-20 11:02:00 |
| APPL | 1980 | 2000 | 1975 | 1988 | 2023-03-20 11:04:00 |

I only have issues with getting the latest close price with in range. right now getting from first row not last row in 2 minute.

Comment: What output does your query produce and how is it incorrect?

Comment: i get the close value of first row in 2 minute grouping not from second row. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, i hope there is no typo

```
select
  open,
  MAX(high) as high,
  MIN(low) as low,
  MAX(IF((minute(time) & 1),close,0)),
  time,
  time - INTERVAL (minute(time) & 1) MINUTE AS quaterhour
from tableName
where ticker = 'APPL'
group by quaterhour
order by quaterhour ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

When [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) is disabled, MySQL allows non-aggregate grouping columns to be omitted, in which case it returns a random row (usually the first row encountered) instead of aggregating. Your query does this.

List all non-aggregating columns in the group by:

```
select
  open,
  MAX(high) as high,
  MIN(low) as low,
  close,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(FLOOR( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)/120 ) * 120) AS quaterhour
from tableName
where ticker = 'APPL'
group by open, close, quaterhour
order by quaterhour ASC
```

You must remove the `time` from the select to aggregate over time.

Also, "quarter" is a poor name choice for a 2-minute period.